# Web API POST not binding

Tags: post, binding, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a SpecialRequest class with just a key inside it.

```
public class SpecialRequest
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

A simple controller

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public SpecialRequest Get()
    {
        return new CodeRequest {SecretKey = "ABSDCV"};
    }

    // POST api/values
    public string Post(SpecialRequest specialRequest)
    {
        string temp = specialRequest.Key + "-TESTING";
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Using fiddler I POST to the Post and I can see it being hit in the debugger but the body of the POST is not bound to the specialRequest parameter in the Post method.

```
Fiddler Headers :
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:64180
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: text/xml


Request Body:
<CodeRequest>
   <SecretKey>
      Hello 
   </SecretKey>
</CodeRequest>
```

What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to add [FromBody] to your method parameter.

```
// GET api/values/5
public SpecialRequest Get(int id)
{
    return new SpecialRequest {Key = "ABC-Key"};
}

// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]SpecialRequest specialRequest)
{
    specialRequest.Key += "Testing";
    // Do something
}
```

2- Your request/content type should be a proper xml  :

i. content type should be **"Content-Type: application/xml"** NOT text/xml.

ii. the body should be :

```
<SpecialRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication2.Controllers">
    <Key>ABC-Key</Key></SpecialRequest>
```

This will definitely fix it.

Hope that helps.

**Edit** 
Just make sure to change the namespace in the passed xml to match your project namespace, so my namespace in this case is WebApplication2.Controllers, make sure to change that to your controller namesapce.

Comment: then you are doing something else somewhere else, that stops this working, because I have a working demo that I published this code from, and I didn't do much, other than defining the SpecialRequest class, then defining the methods as you can see above, and finally run the app and using fiddler I use Post with a body exactly like the above, the only thing that you need to change is the namespace in the xmlns string to match your application namespace ? let me know what happens with you.